# Is there a better way to loop over multiple unknown variables in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

So I have this task where I want to print to a text file. This file includes header information and columns of data with specific names. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

data={'dpr_NS_corZFac': [np.nan, np.nan, 35.736231803894043, 36.331412792205811,
               35.694644451141357, 36.576189994812012, 37.236752510070801,
               38.173699378967285, 38.808069229125977, 36.761274337768555,
               30.194313526153564],
    'dpr_HS_corZFac': [np.nan, 38.550984859466553, 37.893826961517334, 40.246520042419434,
             39.204437732696533, 37.227160930633545, 37.364296913146973,
             40.320019721984863, 39.04454231262207, 33.014707565307617,
             27.193448543548584],
    'npol':[np.nan, np.nan, 35.736231803894043, 36.331412792205811,
               35.694644451141357, 36.576189994812012, 37.236752510070801,
               38.173699378967285, 38.808069229125977, 36.761274337768555,
               30.194313526153564] }

datafile_path = '/home/cpabla/data/pandastext.txt'

with open(datafile_path, 'w+') as f:
    f.write('Charanjit is writing this text file.')
    f.write('\t'*4)
    f.write('He continues to write....\n')
    for tag in data:
        f.write('{}\t\t'.format(tag))
    f.write('\n')
    for val1, val2, val3 in zip(data['dpr_NS_corZFac'], data['dpr_HS_corZFac'], data['npol']):
        if np.isnan(val1): val1 = 99.99
        if np.isnan(val2): val2 = 99.99
        if np.isnan(val3): val3 = 99.99
        f.write('{:.2f}'.format(val1))
        f.write('\t'*7)
        f.write('{:.2f}'.format(val2))
        f.write('\t'*7)
        f.write('{:.2f}'.format(val3))
        f.write('\t'*7)
        f.write('\n')
```

The details of the code is not important as this is simply for testing on my end. Notice how I have a dictionary of lists. I will have an unknown amount of lists in a dictionary and I want to produce a text file of the for given in the example output. But, notice how I loop over multiple variables (in this case lists in my dictionary). I obviously want to automate this so I dont have to keep adding variables to the for loop. So is there a better way to do this?

Here is the output:

```
Charanjit is writing this text file.                He continues to write....
dpr_HS_corZFac      dpr_NS_corZFac      npol
99.99                           99.99                           99.99
99.99                           38.55                           99.99
35.74                           37.89                           35.74
36.33                           40.25                           36.33
35.69                           39.20                           35.69
36.58                           37.23                           36.58
37.24                           37.36                           37.24
38.17                           40.32                           38.17
38.81                           39.04                           38.81
36.76                           33.01                           36.76
30.19                           27.19                           30.19
```

The actual output to a text editor is not like this however. Each column is under its own header name which is exactly what I want. The output is simply to show you what I am trying to do.

Comment: Probably you want `zip(data.values())`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga then they wouldn't be in any particular order.

Comment: Yes, order does matter to me. I want it is the way I have defined the data in the dictionary.

Comment: Well, then your two options are to hard-code it or use an `OrderedDict`

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be :

```
for k in data.keys():
    for val in data[k] :
        if np.isnan(val): val = 99.99
            f.write('{:.2f}'.format(val))
            f.write('\t'*7)
        f.write('\n')
```

Edit : you're right Akasolace, I've edited my code

Comment: Don't iterate over `data.keys()`. It is merely redundant in Python 3. In Python 2, it is less efficient. Use `for key in data:`, although in this case you might want `for sublist in data.values()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np 

data={'dpr_NS_corZFac': [np.nan, np.nan, 35.736231803894043, 36.331412792205811, 
               35.694644451141357, 36.576189994812012, 37.236752510070801, 
               38.173699378967285, 38.808069229125977, 36.761274337768555, 
               30.194313526153564],
    'dpr_HS_corZFac': [np.nan, 38.550984859466553, 37.893826961517334, 40.246520042419434, 
             39.204437732696533, 37.227160930633545, 37.364296913146973, 
             40.320019721984863, 39.04454231262207, 33.014707565307617, 
             27.193448543548584],
    'npol':[np.nan, np.nan, 35.736231803894043, 36.331412792205811, 
               35.694644451141357, 36.576189994812012, 37.236752510070801, 
               38.173699378967285, 38.808069229125977, 36.761274337768555, 
               30.194313526153564] }

datafile_path = r'D:\TEMP\pandastext.txt'

with open(datafile_path, 'w+') as f:
    f.write('Charanjit is writing this text file.')
    f.write('\t'*4)
    f.write('He continues to write....\n')
    for tag in data:
        f.write('{}\t\t'.format(tag))
    f.write('\n')
    for vals in zip(data['dpr_NS_corZFac'], data['dpr_HS_corZFac'], data['npol']):
        for val in vals:
            if np.isnan(val): val = 99.99
            f.write('{:.2f}'.format(val))
            f.write('\t'*7)
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: my answer is similar to the one above ... except for the f.write('\n') which I believe should by outside of the inner loop

Answer (score 0):

Can you use pandas?

Here:

```
In [50]: import pandas as pd

In [48]: pd.set_option('precision', 2)

In [51]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [52]: df
Out[52]:
    dpr_HS_corZFac  dpr_NS_corZFac   npol
0              NaN             NaN    NaN
1            38.55             NaN    NaN
2            37.89           35.74  35.74
3            40.25           36.33  36.33
4            39.20           35.69  35.69
5            37.23           36.58  36.58
6            37.36           37.24  37.24
7            40.32           38.17  38.17
8            39.04           38.81  38.81
9            33.01           36.76  36.76
10           27.19           30.19  30.19


In [56]: df.replace(np.NaN, 99.99, inplace=True)

In [57]: print df.to_string()
    dpr_HS_corZFac  dpr_NS_corZFac   npol
0            99.99           99.99  99.99
1            38.55           99.99  99.99
2            37.89           35.74  35.74
3            40.25           36.33  36.33
4            39.20           35.69  35.69
5            37.23           36.58  36.58
6            37.36           37.24  37.24
7            40.32           38.17  38.17
8            39.04           38.81  38.81
9            33.01           36.76  36.76
10           27.19           30.19  30.19

In [58]:
```

To write to a file (to be complete)

```
In [59]: with open(r'C:\temp\data.txt', 'w') as f:
             f.write("Whatever you want here")
    ...:     f.write(df.to_string(index=False))
    ...:
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. But how would I add the headers I have in my version? For example, Charanjit is writing this text file....

Comment: This seems to work nicely. Is there a way to remove those index or replace them with something else?

Comment: yep... edited.  Also you can just call .to_string(index=False, buf=f)

Comment: So this all works. Problem is once I hit the edge of my text file, the columns start populating below the first column. Somehow python thinks there is no space on the edge of the text file but there should be a way to handle this. Any suggestions? - Update: Never mind, I found the culprit. In the text software, the "word wrap" needs to be un-selected.